# Understanding ping delays

Tags: python, network-programming, delay, ping, mininet

Getting started in class with Mininet and OpenFlow. What I would like to do is add some delay to the ping packets. I've got a basic python script that will add both bandwidth and delay constraints as follows:

```
self.addLink(host1, switch1, bw=10, delay='10ms')
self.addLink(host2, switch1, bw=10, delay='10ms')
self.addLink(host3, switch1, bw=10, delay='10ms')
```

Now, what is confusing me is that the times for each ping packet, seem to be a little weird for me. 
Without a delay my packets look like this:

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.51 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.53 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.27 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.760 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.760/1.230/1.534/0.247 ms
```

I am expecting the delay to 'add 10ms to each packet', however I get the following output when I run ping with a delay of 10ms:

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=85.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=43.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=43.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=42.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=43.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=45.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=43.2 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=45.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=44.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=43.3 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 received, 0% packet loss, time 10019ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.373/47.836/85.146/11.851 ms
```

I can't see that the packets have been delayed explicitly by '10ms'

Is there a reason why my packets time have such a large value? Is it because both the switch and both hosts are adding a delay when I'm pinging them, hence the increase in time?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say what you've done is you added a 10ms delay to EACH host, so to both `h1` and `h2`, hence doing the math: 10ms to pass from `h1` to `switch1`, 10ms to pass from `switch1` to `h2`, 10ms for response to pass from `h2` to `switch1`, 10 ms to pass from `switch1` to `h2`: `10+10+10+10=40`. Seems legit to me.

Answer (score 0):

Between h1 and h2 there are two links, each with a 10ms delay. So it takes packets around 20ms to travel in one direction. So a round trip takes around 40ms.

Since a ping consists of a pair of packets - [ICMP Echo Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29#Echo_request) (sent by the source) and [ICMP Echo reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29#Echo_reply) (sent by the target), you get a delay of about 40ms for all pings starting with the second one.

The reason for the longer delay in the first ping is slightly trickier. For a pair of hosts to exchange IP level messages in a LAN (e.g. through a switch), they have to know each other's MAC addresses. Before the first packet, h1 doesn't know the MAC of h2, so it has to resolve it. The resolution consists of a pair of packets - an ARP request, sent by h1, and an ARP response sent by h2. These messages also travel for 40ms in the LAN. Only once the response is received, can the first ICMP packet be sent. That's how you get the 80ms delay.